# How mongodb connection works on concurrent requests in NodeJS express server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am new to mongoDB and I'm currently working on setting it up with Node express server. I wonder how to manage concurrent requests to the mongodb to read the collection data using the mongoose driver module.

**For example:**

If 100 users are accessing my server at a time (http://xxxxxx.com/showusers), how will the mongodb connection in the express server work? Will it be a single connection or split into 100 connections, one for each request?

How can I close the connection object in mongodb efficiently after the operation? Or can we leave the connection in the express server as in the below code?

Here follows my code..

### Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('port', config.port);



  app.get('/users',storeusersapi.showUsers);

  app.get('/storeUser',storeusersapi._insertUserDetails);

  app.get('/findUser/:email',storeusersapi._findUser);

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
   log.info('Express app started on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

### storeusersapi.js

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var log = require('../config/logger');

// Mongoose connection to MongoDB (ted/ted is readonly)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function (error) {
if (error) {
    log.error("MongoDB Connection failure - " +error);
}else{
    log.info('MongoDB is connected Successfully!!!');
}
});

// Mongoose Schema definition
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
first_name: String,
last_name: String,
email: String
});

// Mongoose Model definition
var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

exports.showUsers = function(req,res){
User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
};

exports._insertUserDetails = function(req,res){
   var object = new User({first_name:'bob',last_name:'sel',email:'sel@xxxxx.com'});

object.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        log.error('Insertion error - '+ err);
    }
    else {
        log.info("User Stored into database!!!");
    }
});




};

exports._findUser = function(req,res){
User.find({ email: req.params.email }, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});

};
```

Comment: did you get anything on this or not ??

Answer (score 0):

I have answered for both of your question separately.

**1. How will the mongodb connection in the express server work?**

Once a connection is created to the mongodb database.(using mongoose or any other framework) It will create a pool of connections with that. *(Mongoose default pool size is 5, 100 in python)* The created connection pool is maintained by the driver therefore those connections can be re-used when connections to the database are required.

The best practice is to create a new connection only once for the whole application. Once connection is created the connection object will be used as a singleton. When you connect to the database using mongoose models, separate connections are allocated from the created connection pool.

If you are going to create a new connection each time then It will cause to a connection churn.

**2. How can I close the connection object in mongodb efficiently after the operation ?**

I am not sure 100% about this answer. My suggestion is to disconnect the connection when the express application exits.

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database');    
db.disconnect();
```

According to my knowledge what you have don in the code is correct. You have created a new connection only once. Since the connection pool is created with that you don't need to create more connections.

Please go through this link to get a clear understanding on connection pools and their usage.
https://dzone.com/articles/deep-dive-connection-pooling